# JavaScript - mousemove event not triggered on iPad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, ipad, mousemove, onmousemove

I worked for a while on E-learning project, where I had to script an HTML file that's loaded on a global framework. I used to use:

`$('#myobject').on('mousedown' ... 'mousemove' ... 'mouseup' , function(){}`)

And it worked well everywhere (Chrome, IE, iOS ... etc)

Now I am working on a personal project, and in the browser everything is working well, but 'mousemove' does not seem to get triggered  on iDevices (iPad, iPhone ... etc).

Here is simple code I wrote, that doesn't work on an iPad:

```
    $(window).load(function() {

        document.ontouchmove = function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }   

        $(document).on('mousemove',onmm);
        function onmm(e){
            var a = e.pageX;
            var b = e.pageY;
            $('#txt1').html(a);
            $('#txt2').html(b);
        }

    });
```

Any help ?

Comment: So you use your company's proprietary framework for your own pet project stuff (BTW, are you sure it is legal to do so?), it does not work, and would like to get help from us - who didn't work on that framework?

Comment: On touch devices, the mouse events are *simulated* based on touch events. If you're killing the default behavior of "touchmove", you're probably preventing the synthesis of a "mousemove".

Comment: ppeterka , what do you mean dude ? since when the code that u can provide from the HTML - CSS - Javascript are illegal ? except the fact that u can minify your script (which is the case with the company i'v been working with) , no boddy can say that it's illegal to COPY - PASTE a code (even if am not doing that) ... you know already this i guess . A help from would be better !!

Comment: And 2nd if am using the stuff of my company , i wouldn't be here asking for this too basic issues...

Answer (score 2):

Just use jquery.event.move. Move events provide an easy way to set up press-move-release interactions on mouse AND touch devices. So you don't have to worry which device your users have.

Source and examples: http://stephband.info/jquery.event.move/